# Can't Get Specific Folder Action To Work

Tags: macos, applescript, directory

Having a bit of a problem here.  I'm trying to get a specific Folder Action to work, but no matter what I do, I just can't seem to get it working.  All my other folder actions work as expected, even the ones I've AppleScript'd myself.  But, not this one.  Heres' the code:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
--set added_items to choose file with multiple selections allowed
processItems(added_items)

end adding folder items to

on processItems(added_items)

set imageTypesList to {"JPEG image", "Portable Network Graphics image", "Windows bitmap image", "Graphics Interchange Format image", "Adobe Photoshop File", "TIFF Image"}

set audioTypesList to {"MP3 audio", "AIFF-C audio", "Waveform audio"}
set videoTypesList to {"Video-MPEG4", "MPEG-4 File", "Video-MPEG2", "Video-MPEG", "AVI", "Matroska Video File"}
set fontTypesList to {"TrueType font", "PostScript® Type 1 outline font", "Font Suitcase"}
set docsTypesList to {"Portable Document Format (PDF)", "Scrivener Project", "Microsoft Word 97 - 2004 document", "Rich Text Document", "Plain Text Document", "CSV Document", "Pages Publication", "Keynote Presentation"}
set epubTypesList to {"epub", "Kindle Document", "iBooks Author Template", "iBooks Author Book"}
set archTypesList to {"ZIP archive", "tar archive", "rar archive", "Tar Gzip Archive"}
set diskTypesList to {"Installer package", "Disk Image"}
set execTypesList to {"Unix Executable File"}
set appsTypesList to {"Application (32-bit)", "Application"}
set iconTypesList to {"Apple Icon Image", "Icon Container", "Windows Icon Image"}
set otherTypesList to {"XTorrent File"}
set scriptTypesList to {"Compiled OSA Script"}
set openTypesList to {"Chromium Extra", "Action", "RapidWeaver Theme", "Mac OS X Preference Pane"}

set uberList to imageTypesList & audioTypesList & videoTypesList & fontTypesList & docsTypesList & ¬
    epubTypesList & archTypesList & diskTypesList & execTypesList & appsTypesList & iconTypesList & ¬
    otherTypesList & scriptTypesList & openTypesList

set imagesFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Images" as alias
set appsFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Apps" as alias
set archivesFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Archives" as alias
set epubFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:eBooks" as alias
set fontsFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Fonts" as alias
set docsFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:PDFs and Docs" as alias
set diskFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Installers and Disk Images" as alias
set iconFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Icons" as alias
set audioFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Audio" as alias
set videoFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Video" as alias
set otherFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Torrent Files" as alias
set miscFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Miscellanious" as alias
set scriptFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:AppleScripts and Automator Stuff" as alias
set execFolder to "Technomage:Users:andyhainline:Downloads:Run From Here" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with anItem in added_items
        if (kind of anItem) is in imageTypesList then
            move file anItem to imagesFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in audioTypesList then
            move file anItem to audioFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in videoTypesList then
            move file anItem to videoFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in fontTypesList then
            move file anItem to fontsFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in docsTypesList then
            move file anItem to docsFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in epubTypesList then
            move file anItem to epubFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in archTypesList then
            move file anItem to archivesFolder with replacing
            open (path to archiveFolder & (name of file anItem))
        else if (kind of anItem) is in diskTypesList then
            move file anItem to diskFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in execTypesList then
            move file anItem to appsFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in webTypesList then
            move file anItem to docsFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in iconTypesList then
            move file anItem to iconFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in otherTypesList then
            move file anItem to otherFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in scriptTypes then
            move file anItem to scriptFolder with replacing
        else if (kind of anItem) is in openTypes then
            delay 10
            open anItem
            move file anItem to miscFolder
        else if (kind of anItem is "Folder") then
            set folderFiles to get every file of folder anItem
            processItems(folderFiles)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

end processItems

As you can see, it's rather complex.   Please note:  If I comment out the "on" handlers at the beginning and just run the script with a "choose files" dialog, it works perfectly, just as expected.  So, there is -- theoretically -- nothing wrong with the code itself.  I've checked my file permissions of the file in "/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts", and this is what I get:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  20758 Sep  2 14:43 add - copy based on type.scpt
```

Which to me looks exactly right.  (I had to set these permissions manually after saving the file.)

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

--A.H.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you expect added_items to be a list of files, thus you use a repeat loop. I suspect that maybe when only 1 file is added that it isn't a list and therefore the repeat loop doesn't work. As such I suggest checking the class of added_items and proceeding accordingly. So try changing the top part of the script to this...

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    --set added_items to choose file with multiple selections allowed
    if (class of added_items) is list then
        processItems(added_items)
    else
        processItems({added_items}) -- here we make it a list so the repeat loop works
    end if
end adding folder items to
```